# How to write out a column vector

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, vector, latex

How do I add a column vector as text to my plot using matplotlib?

For example:

[image]

Is there a way of writing this using plt.text()? The closest I've got is writing it out as a fraction, although not encapsulated by brackets:

```
plt.text(0,0, r'$\frac{x}{y}$')
```

However, as it's a vector, I effectively need a line-less fraction contained within brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a 2-vector, you can use the [`\binom{}{}`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Fractions_and_Binomials) LaTeX command.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.text(0, 0, r"$\binom{x}{y}$", fontsize=100, ha="center", va="center")
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way of removing that whitespace to the right of the terms, prior to the closing bracket?

Comment: That's just the LaTeX spacing. I'm not sure how to adjust that in this case.